# Exception Return from two different lists to Json - WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, exception

I have a WCF REST service that returns Json. I have a Client App passing detail in Json, get deserialized in the API, a query gets run on SQL with the incoming ID's and then a value for each corresponding ID is returned. This works fine. I now have a need to design custom exception handling. The only difference is, I have to instead of now returning a "List" object, if successful take this "List" and append a **Result** array at the bottom which, the idea is to give the client an indication of whether or not an exception occurred.

I started off with **WebHttpException**, which apparently is not desired, so I am now re-thinking my options.

I am basically thinking of an "Intercepting" method which takes the list of returned data, getting another list or object with **CustomErrorDetail** which will contain ErrorID (which we specify), ErrorDetail (also hard-coded yep), and ErrorDate (DateTime.Now). I can then have this interceptor method get all the strings from the Data List and just append the single CustomErrorDetail at the bottom which will then be made to JSon, and in turn this will be returned in another JSon string back to the client??

This seems a bit extreme. IS there not perhaps a more elegant, better performing way to do this?

I basically am planning on getting something like this before I return it to the Client app wrapped inside another JSon string:

```
[
  [
  {
    "ID": "G0000013",
    "Balance": ""
  },
  {
    "ID": "G0000015",
    "Balance": ""
  },
  {
    "ID": "G0000017",
    "Balance": ""
  },
  {
    "ID": "G0000019",
    "Balance": ""
  }
  ],
  [
  {
    "ErrorID": "2",
    "ErrorDetail": "Failed!!!"
  }  
  ]
]
```

Excuse the excruciating detail. Any help, advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make your object have a status and message property where the Message could be the Balance etc{ "ID": "0123456", "Status": "Success/Error/Terminated", "Message": "Whatever" }

Comment: Also thought of that @Lloyd, however, the requirement is for one exception message for multiple items. Similar to what is returned in XML in some services. Not quite gonna work for what we have to do.

Comment: If each item has its own status and message then you can return as little or as much information as you want. without the wasted need to parse a SOAP or other Web Exception

Comment: @Lloyd, no we definitely don't want SOAP. We also don't want web exceptions. Basically we just want what is returned up until the Json part above where the second part with ErrorID etc. starts. So, we basically just need the standard response that is returned by the SQL query, and then inserted into a list and add a little piece of JSon at the bottom before we return it. So, get List content, JSon inject Results part at bottom and return. Not my decision. We need Custom exceptions returned to client.

Comment: Json does not inject anything, you return typed data serialized in either Json or XML so you either create your model two collections, one for the returned data and one for the exception messages!